# Get the statistics from a key value file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a file with content

```
Test_CG:
    Copy stats:
      Test_CG:
        SAN traffic:
          Current throughput: 22832 bps
          Average  throughput: 1 Mbps
          Current write IOPS: 1
          Average write IOPS: 4

      Test_CG_DR:
        Journal:
          Usage: 477.13MB
          Total: 2.45GB
          Latest image: Fri Apr 11 11:03:04.561405 2014
          Current image: Fri Apr 11 11:03:04.561405 2014
          Journal lag: 130.18MB
          Protection window:N/A
          Average journal compression ratio:N/A
          Mode: Normal
    Link stats:
      Test_CG -> Test_CG_DR:
        Init:
          SAN traffic: 134 Mbps
          WAN traffic: 79 Mbps
          Progress: 80.68%
        Replication:
          Lag:
            Time: 30 sec
            Data: 52.57MB
            Writes: 886
          WAN traffic: 13 Mbps
          Current bandwidth reduction ratio: 1.08711
          Average bandwidth reduction ratio: 1.09669
          Current deduplication ratio:N/A
          Average deduplication ratio:N/A
```

I want to get the WAN Traffic data from 2 Sections, from Link Stats and from Replication

I have it done with lot of Text processing using ruby, But I think it has to be structured,

Can I do something with JSON or YAML with ruby ?

Actually any technique will help.

Regards,

A

Comment: This doesn't parse as YAML. You need a space before "N/A". Do you have control over what generates this file, or are you stuck with the file as is?

Comment: I am stuck with the file as is

Comment: I can add a space there by some technique though

Comment: Once you fix that space formatting, `YAML.load` reads it into a hash just fine. Then you can index out the values you want.

Comment: Thats perfect, it works

Comment: however, there are 2 values of "WAN Traffic", hash ignores the 2nd Value, Is it possible to get around this?

Comment: I know that defeats the purpose of a Hash

Comment: They should be under different keys: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse it as `YAML` you have to fix the formatting: there should be a space before `N/A`. If this is a consistent formatting glitch, you can do that with `gsub`.

```
require 'yaml'
file_contents = load_my_file()
cleaned_yaml = file_contents.gsub(/:N\/A/, ': N/A')
hash = YAML.load(cleaned_yaml)

hash['Test_CG']['Link stats']['Test_CG -> Test_CG_DR']['Init']['WAN traffic']
# => "79 Mbps"
hash['Test_CG']['Link stats']['Test_CG -> Test_CG_DR']['Replication']['WAN traffic']
# => "13 Mbps"
```

This works for the provided sample.

Your mileage may vary when you run it with real data.

Comment: This is just amazing, what you have given is the exact thing

Comment: Hi, I can not thank you enough for this.I not only learnt about YAML, also got some idea about the hashes which I was so scared of.Now my script is complete and running. Thanks a lot